# Impedance of 4 conductor system spaced horizontally apart

Tags: resistance, skin-effect

I have 4 cylindrical conductors spaced equally and horizontally apart. How can I calculate the magnitude of Impedance (Z) using the Skin effect and Proximity effect?

I'm looking for an equation that will output Z given things such as the cross sectional area, length, frequency, and physical constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one answer; you need to consider each possible pairing of wires individually. With symmetry, there are four unique cases. The formula can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin-lead#Characteristic_impedance).

Comment: Take a look at this link, as well, it may provide some extra useful things: http://www.openelectrical.org/wiki/index.php?title=Cable_Impedance_Calculations